# how do i fix this Uncaught ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, referenceerror

I am pretty new to java script. I am following along on a tutorial on how to get firebase to authorize on my page. I just have a simple button that SHOULD pull up the google login.

The error is "(index):96 Uncaught ReferenceError: googlelogin is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):96)
onclick @ (index):96"

Im pretty certain this is an easy fix. Like I said, fairly new. Thanks in advance!

In the HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>testing</h1>
    <button onclick="googlelogin()">login</button> 

    <script>
        src = "app.js"
    </script>
</body>
```

In app.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMcontentloaded", event => {

        const app = firebase.app();
        console.log(app)

    )
}

function googlelogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

    firebase.auth().signupwithpopup(provider)

    .then(result => {
            const user = result.user
            document.write('Hello $(user.displayname');
            console.log(user)
        })
        .catch(console.log)
```

Comment: The `src` attribute goes inside the tag: `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code just sets a global variable called `src` to the value of `app.js`. I think you want to actually *load* `app.js`

```
<body>
    <h1>testing</h1>
    <button onclick="googlelogin()">login</button> 

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```